# ANDROID : Modification of my layout in real time

Tags: java, android, layout

I experience some trouble to update my layout in real time on my application.

I would like to show a first screen with a button "Load Data".
When I press the button, I want to change the text to "Loading..." and make a progress bar appear while the app is loading the data. When it's done, I'd like to change again the text to "launch app" and to make disepear the progress bar.

The issue I have is that the text in the button doesn't refrech, and the progressiv bar doesn't show up...

I've tried a lot of things, with and without thread, looking for help on the internet but i couldn't find any suitable tip.

Maybe you have an idea to help me? :D

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    button.setText("Load Data");
    findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

private void appInit() {
            try {
                ((MyApp) getApplication()).getDataFromServer();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ((MyApp) getApplication()).initData();

}


@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
    if(buttonText=="Load Data"){
        findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button.setText("Loading");
        appInit();
        while(!((MyApp)this.getApplication()).isInitSucceded()){}
        button.setText("Launch App");
        findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ddcorp.test.Resume.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn about [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) - they are designed to help you perform background tasks (like your appInit method) and update the UI easily.

Comment: You can do that with help of AsyncTask - see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275913/show-progress-dialog-while-loading-data

Comment: 2016 and still using AsyncTask is sad. Go for RxAndroid, it's kinda of difficult to start, but after it's easy and much much much more powerful than AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocking a UI thread with the following line is not a good idea:

```
while(!((MyApp)this.getApplication()).isInitSucceded()){}
```

alternatively you can use AsyncTask which has methods for background process, progress update, and post execution logic. Here is an example:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,String>
{
    @override
    public String doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
         //do your background processes
         ...
         publishProgress(someInteger); //for updating progress bar
         ...
         return result;
    }

    @override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... params)
    {
         //do your progress bar update with params[0]
    }

    @override
    public void onPostExecute(String.. params)
    {
         //do something with the results of doInBackground stored in params[0]
    }
}
```

and here is how to call it:

```
(new MyTask()).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if(buttontext.equals("Load Data")){
  ..
 }
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to tell where my problem was. In fact, the text just donesn't refresh and the progressiv bar doesn't show up :/ My code is correct but i don't know why, the operations onf the layout aren't effective

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution if it can help someone someday :D

```
Button button;
ProgressBar progress;
private Context mContext;
MyApp mApplication;
public Init(Context context){
    mContext = context;
    mApplication = (MyApp) mContext.getApplicationContext();
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    ProgressBar progress=(ProgressBar)((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    button=(Button)((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setText("Loading");
    button.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.lgreen));
}

@Override
public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
        mApplication.getDataFromServer();
        mApplication.initData();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}


protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    ProgressBar progress=(ProgressBar)((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    button=(Button)((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setText("Launch");
    button.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    System.out.println("ok");
}
```